# Progress Bar for a parent group of Marker Cluster Groups

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I would like to add a Progress Bar to my map in the following manner: http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.markercluster/example/marker-clustering-realworld.50000.html

The problem is that I am using children featureGroups in a parent cluster group, so that I can remove and add layers easily while keeping my clusters displayed.
I have tried the following two methods:

- [Leaflet.MarkerCluster.LayerSupport](https://github.com/ghybs/Leaflet.MarkerCluster.LayerSupport): the loading bar does not work at all when I try:

  var mcgLayerSupportGroup = L.markerClusterGroup.layerSupport({ chunkedLoading: true,
              chunkProgress: updateProgressBar});
- [Leaflet.FeatureGroup.SubGroup](https://github.com/ghybs/Leaflet.FeatureGroup.SubGroup): the loading bar is displayed, but not for the overall markers added. Instead it is computed for each marker subgroup. The loading bar may disappear, then appear again, etc.

  var parentGroup = L.markerClusterGroup({ chunkedLoading: true,
              chunkProgress: updateProgressBar});

My best attempt so far has been to tweak the updateProgressBar, but my code is far from being effective (slow and approximate the behavior of a progress bar):

```
var tot_processed=0;
//this total_markers variable is computed when I call my API endpoints and compute the total number of markers
var total_markers;

function updateProgressBar(processed, total, elapsed, layersArray) {
    tot_processed += processed;
    if (total_trees - tot_processed > 1000) {
        progress.style.display = 'block';
        progressBar.style.width = Math.round(tot_processed/total_trees*100) + '%';
    } else {
        if (processed === total) {
            // all markers processed - hide the progress bar:
            progress.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you very much!